# Check value inside IFrame before post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe, webforms

I am using an IFrame in my WebForm aspx page. I fill in the data in the IFrame, IFrame has the auto post when all data is filled. 
I click the Server Side button that posts the page back to the server, I need to check a certain value in of the IFrame before I post back in the page.
I have added on client click javascript function to server side button to investigate if the value is populated for the element inside IFrame. 
I get cross-origin error. Is there a way to check/wait for the iframe to populate the element inside it before I trigger my server side code ?

Comment: If you getting the cross origin error then the iframe url is not coming from the same host as the web application. You can't do anything in that case.

Comment: only if you control the code in the iframe page source...do you?

Comment: I use 3rd party js library that injects HTML in my aspx page.